# Need to restrict the user to a single browser session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have built an ASP.Net MVC site using Forms Authentication for a client.
Recently, they have requested that an authenticated user be restricted to a single browser session.  That is, if the user raises a new browser instance, or opens a new tab on the original browser window, that he/she be logged out of the original.  They insist on the added security.
Does anyone know how I might approach this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, people for the suggestions.  Each had strong merits, however I had to take a hybrid approach.  I found an incredibly simple suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850058/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-a-user-has-opened-a-link-in-a-new-tab/13688467#13688467).

I implemented table of active users as Karl suggested as well.  This will give the client the ability of deactivating the user on demand.
Thanks again.

Comment: i too had the same requirement can you please help me!..what all are the things you have done??

Comment: What worked for me was a hybrid approach of generating a GUID value for the user upon login, and maintaining that user session in a table of sessions. I added some simple javascript as a 'heartbeat' mechanism to refresh the entry in the sessions table for as long as the user was active.

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment. How did you killed the last opened window(log out).Have you used any kind of authentication(Like forms authentication or something else)?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would push back and ask exactly what security this is bringing.  Maintaining state like this counter to web architecture and is only going to bring you and your users grief.

Comment: I did push back - hard.  Lobbied the owner as well.  They insisted, likely due to the network admin.

Comment: @phil1630  Well you tried.  It is sad when network admins are able to exert so much influence on something they obviously haven't thought too hard about.  Anyway, you are left with keeping some kind of thread safe collection of authorization cookies that where you kill an old one when the same user logs in again.  Not sure how that will work with ASP.NET Forms auth, I don't have much experience with that particular mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I would do if presented with this problem:

1. Store the username of the user in your database (i.e. LoggedOn table).
2. When a user logs on, check to see if their username is already present in the LoggedOn table.
3. If the user isn't already logged on, insert a row into the table with the username and the current time; otherwise present the user with a message informing them that they can only log into the system from one device at a time.
4. Include logic to expire and delete the rows in the table if a user's session expires or if the user logs out.

Answer (score 2):

First a disclaimer: I'm no expert in web programming.

Perhaps you might try a system where every user interaction requires the submission of a random value that's been generated for that page (much like what's used for [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF) protection.) That key could be kept under the user's session information on the server, and if a page is ever requested without the correct key as a URL parameter, the session is invalidated. The URL from one browser won't work in another, either, since once a URL is gone to, the user's session key has changed. The only way for a user to transfer a session between tabs would be to copy the URL of an unclicked link and paste it in a new tab's address bar. Switching browsers would be even more complex assuming that ASP.Net uses a session cookie: the user would have to transfer the cookie from one browser to another. Going back would also fail, as all the links on the previous page, and the URL for the page, would carry an incorrect session key.

Also, for reference, I believe the US Gov't [TreasuryDirect](http://www.treasurydirect.gov) site works in the way you've described, though I've never looked at how they manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as one active view at a time instead of one browser or tab.   Or convince the customer to view it this way.

You can always issue a unique cookie for the browser session (ASP.NET Session) and allow communication to the latest cookie issued effectively making only one session active at a time, and therefore rendering other open sessions (browsers, tabs, etc) useless with the app by disallowing them communication any longer or serving up an error page for them. To do so you have to recognize who the user is and authenticate them against your app.  This is half the puzzle and will force the user down to use your app in only a single browser at a time on their machine.

The other part of the problem is to pare down the windows and tabs that are part of the *same browsing session* of that browser, to allow only one view to be active at a time. To do so you can issue a unique sequential ID to the viewstate of each page for postback to the server to uniquely identify that page apart from other pages sharing the same session state (whether that page be in a browser tab, a frame or new window, etc). Or a code of your choice that's traceable.  You then know which page is posting back within the session and can disallow others or deactivate previous ones by, again, shutdown down communication in some manner or serving up an error page, etc.

A new browser instance or a new tab may or may not be part of the same browsing session depending on how the browser is configured.  I believe, for example, IE provides a setting that allows the behaviour to be set of whether a tab opens in a new process or session or shares the session. You won't necessarily get expected consistency across browsers to rely on for this feature, therefore you need to take programming steps to reign it in, like those described above.

You can additional steps like disallowing the user to be connected from a different IP# at the same time.