# Stop opening other browser or external source using angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing

When a user is taking his interview, how to detect if he is opening a new window or any other external source?

For Example: If 2 persons are having a video call in watsapp , if any one of the person opens any application , a message is displayed on the screen "**Your Video is Paused**"

How can we bring this in angular 6 using recordRTC or WebRTC

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/850058/7344609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using document.focus which can detect the user opening a new tab and a external application

TS

```
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let log = document.getElementById('log');

if (document.hasFocus()) {
log.textContent = 'This document has the focus.';
body.style.background = '#fff';
}
else {
log.textContent = 'This document does not have the focus.';
body.style.background = '#ccc';
}
```

HTML

```
<p id="log">Awaiting focus check.</p>
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You can't and it's probably for the better. You can only determine if your tab isn't focused [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active). It would be a security nightmare if applications/sites can "spy" on users via javascript